# Fit Datagridview result in one page vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I can see a lot of questions regarding multiple page printpreview in vb.net using datagridview. My question is, is it possible to fit the result of a datagridview in just `one page` in printpreview? My table only exceeds at least two to three rows for the next page. I need to have it consolidated in just one page instead of having it printed on the next page.

How do we do that>

Comment: Obviously, if you want to print something in a smaller area, i.e. one page instead of two, then you have to make it smaller. That means using a smaller font or making the space between the rows smaller. Simples.

Comment: or bigger page :] (decrease the page margins or zoom)

Comment: I was thinking of manipulating the table..